# Set Specific IIS 7 Site with AppCmd?

Tags: authentication, iis-7, batch-file, scripting

I have an IIS 7 machine with multiple apps/vdirs on the single default
web site. I would like to set two of them with this authentication:
anonymous - off
impersonation - on
forms auth - off
windows auth - on

I would like to do this with appcmd.exe but cannot seem to get the
syntax down right. Has anyone had luck with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should try Configuration Editor (included in IIS 7.5 and available for download for IIS 7.0 at http://www.iis.net/download/AdministrationPack), it can generate the AppCmd.exe commands automatically as well as javascript and managed code. Using it I generated the following (for default web site):

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication /enabled:"False"  

appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.web/identity /impersonate:"True"  

appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication /enabled:"True"  /commit:apphost
```

Note that the ones with commit:apphost are because the sections are locked by default which means they need to be set inside ApplicationHost.config using location paths.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks! I had no idea that was in the administration pack.

Answer (score 4):

unlock first:

```
appcmd unlock config /section:windowsAuthentication
```

refer to: [How to set authentication with appcmd.exe or ServerManager](http://forums.iis.net/t/1146296.aspx?How%20to%20set%20authentication%20with%20appcmd%20exe%20or%20ServerManager)